# A formatted print function to insert integers is returning an error. How do I fix this?

Tags: python

Essentially, I am trying to seamlessly insert an integer into a print function.

This is what I have so far:

```
a=1
b=2
c=3
d=6
print(f'{a} plus {b} plus {c} equals {d}')
```

This results in a "SyntaxError: cannot mix bytes and nonbytes literals". 
Is this edition of Python just wrong for this code? What is wrong?

Comment: working fine to me, cann't reproduce the error. which python, ide you are using ?

Comment: Please edit your post to specify the exact Python version, and make sure the snippet you posted is a proper reproducible example (it should trigger the exact same error each time you execute it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works for me, alternativley you can use the format function:

```
a=1
b=2
c=3
d=6
print('{} plus {} plus {} equals {}'.format(a,b,c,d))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using f-strings, which can only be used in Python 3.6 and above.

I've a feeling your python version is the problem. Run `python --version`.

That said, I've run it in python2.7 and python3.5 and not been able to recreate the exact error message. The closest I got was 3.5 with this

```
# python3.5 go.py
  File "go.py", line 5
    print(f'{a} plus {b} plus {c} equals {d}')
                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

You used f-strings which is new in Python 3.6

I'm pretty sure that your version of python is prior to 3.6

You can read [this link](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) to get more informations on this and find alternative solutions.